# How to indent Python list-comprehensions?

Tags: python, coding-style

List comprehensions can be useful in certain situations, but they can also be rather horrible to read.. As a slightly exaggerated example, how would you indent the following?

```
allUuids = [x.id for x in self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout = 20) if x.type == "post" and x.deleted is not False]
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It depends on how long they are. I tend to structure them like so:

```
[x.id for x
 in self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout=20)
 if x.type == 'post' 
    and x.deleted is not False
    and ...
    and ...]
```

That way every expression has its own line.

If any line becomes too big I like to extract it out in a lambda or expression:

```
transform = lambda x: x.id
results = self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout=20)
condition = lambda x: x.deleted is not False and ... and ...
[transform(x) for x in results if condition(x)]
```

And then if a lambda becomes too long it gets promoted to a function.

Comment: these are NOT equivalent - the list comprehension is many times faster, as it doesn't have to do any function lookups. the appropriate translation would use for loops.

Comment: Except for the performance hit , this is a very readable example !

Comment: How would for loops prevent the function lookup? Also note that the loop in list comprehensions is implemented in C, and is therefore faster than the plain one.

Comment: Just a note -- you can use multiple if statements instead of using "and" multiple times. Kind of a funny little syntax truth.

Comment: pycodestyle emits `E131 continuation line unaligned for hanging indent` for this.

Comment: [Continuation line over-indented for visual indent (E127)](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E127.html). Fixed by aligning `if` and `and`.

Answer (score 58):

Where I work, our coding guidelines would have us do something like this:

```
all_posts_uuid_query = self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid)
all_posts_uuid_list = all_posts_uuid_query.execute(timeout=20)
all_uuid_list = [
    x.id 
    for x in all_posts_uuid_list 
    if (
        x.type == "post" 
        and 
        not x.deleted  # <-- if you don't care about NULLs / None
    )
]
```

Comment: [Continuation line unaligned for hanging indent (E131)](https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E131.html)

Answer (score 8):

```
allUuids = [x.id 
            for x in self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout = 20) 
            if x.type == "post" and x.deleted is not False]
```

Answer (score 6):

For me that's too much. Maybe it's just a terrible example, since "type" and "deleted" would clearly be part of the db query.

I tend to think that if a list comprehension spans multiple lines it probably shouldn't be a list comprehension. Having said that, I usually just split the thing at "if" like other people have and will answer here.

Answer (score 3):

**You should not use a list comprehension for that**.

List comprehensions are an awesome feature, but they are meant to be shortcuts, not regular code.

For such a long snippet, you should use ordinary blocs :

```
allUuids = []
for x in self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout = 20) :
    if x.type == "post" and x.deleted is not False :
        allUuids.append(x.id)
```

Exactly the same behavior, much more readable. Guido would be proud of you :-)

Comment: this is a teeny bit slower, as you have to build the array step by step

Comment: I think the list comprehension does exactly the same under the hood. It's not because it's a one line expression that this is a one time operation...

Comment: e-statis: the function is the same, but list comprehensions can be significantly faster

Comment: This way employs mutable, non-functional style. Immutability allows thinking in terms of mapping and filtering. In this code, list is changed and reader has to keep in mind that it can be changed afterwards. It's better to make generator function with `yield` than this, or introduce new variables and functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you're set on a comprehension [orestis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311604/1887870) is good.

For more complex comprehensions like that I'd suggest using a generator with `yield`:

```
allUuids = list(self.get_all_uuids())


def get_all_uuids(self):
    for x in self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout = 20):
        if x.type == "post" and x.deleted is not False:
            yield x.id
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
allUuids = [x.id for x in self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout = 20) 
                   if (x.type == "post" and x.deleted is not False)]
```

Generally, long lines can be avoided by pre-computing subexpressions into variables, which might add a minuscule performance cost:

```
query_ids = self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout = 20)
allUuids = [x.id for x in query_ids
                   if (x.type == "post" and x.deleted is not False)]
```

By the way, isn't '`is not False`' kind-of superfluous ? Are you worried about differentiating between None and False ? Because otherwise, it suffices to leave the condition as only: i`f (x.type == "post" and x.deleted)`

Comment: I second that. Generally lines of more than 80 characters should be avoided in all languages.

Comment: Agreed, but Python's syntax rules often encourage/force longer lines. Its whitespace handling in general is about my only complaint about the language.

Comment: With carefully chosen variables, and spliting lines with parenthesis or brackets, i never had to resort to too long lines (the problem is more often to avoid self.long_foo.very_long_bar.baz(....) using temporaries)

Comment: About the "By the way", it is not totally superfluous, take the case x.deleted = None, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
    allUuids = [
        x.id
        for x in self.db.query(schema.allPostsUuid).execute(timeout = 20)
        if x.type == "post"
            and x.deleted
    ]
```