# Line continuation for list comprehensions or generator expressions in python

Tags: python, coding-style, list-comprehension, pep8

How are you supposed to break up a very long list comprehension?

```
[something_that_is_pretty_long for something_that_is_pretty_long in somethings_that_are_pretty_long]
```

I have also seen somewhere that people that dislike using '\' to break up lines,
but never understood why. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to indent Python list-comprehensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311588/how-to-indent-python-list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
[x
 for
 x
 in
 (1,2,3)
]
```

works fine, so you can pretty much do as you please. I'd personally prefer

```
 [something_that_is_pretty_long
  for something_that_is_pretty_long
  in somethings_that_are_pretty_long]
```

The reason why `\` isn't appreciated very much is that it appears at the *end* of a line, where it either doesn't stand out or needs extra padding, which has to be fixed when line lengths change:

```
x = very_long_term                     \
  + even_longer_term_than_the_previous \
  + a_third_term
```

In such cases, use parens:

```
x = (very_long_term
     + even_longer_term_than_the_previous
     + a_third_term)
```

Comment: Specifically, line breaks are ignored inside *any* brackets - `()`, `[]` and `{}`.

Answer (score 29):

You can also make use of multiple indentations in cases where you're dealing with a list of several data structures.

```
new_list = [
    {
        'attribute 1': a_very_long_item.attribute1,
        'attribute 2': a_very_long_item.attribute2,
        'list_attribute': [
            {
                'dict_key_1': attribute_item.attribute2,
                'dict_key_2': attribute_item.attribute2
            }
            for attribute_item
            in a_very_long_item.list_of_items
         ]
    }
    for a_very_long_item
    in a_very_long_list
    if a_very_long_item not in [some_other_long_item
        for some_other_long_item 
        in some_other_long_list
    ]
]
```

Notice how it also filters onto another list using an if statement. Dropping the if statement to its own line is useful as well.

Answer (score 24):

I'm not opposed to:

```
variable = [something_that_is_pretty_long
            for something_that_is_pretty_long
            in somethings_that_are_pretty_long]
```

You don't need `\` in this case. In general, I think people avoid `\` because it's slightly ugly, but also can give problems if it's not the very last thing on the line (make sure no whitespace follows it). I think it's much better to use it than not, though, in order to keep your line lengths down.

Since `\` isn't necessary in the above case, or for parenthesized expressions, I actually find it fairly rare that I even need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that you shouldn't use a list comprehension in this case, and instead use a `for` loop:

```py
result = []
for something_that_is_pretty_long in somethings_that_are_pretty_long:
    result.append(something_that_is_pretty_long)
```

One reason to use list comprehensions over a `for` loop + `.append()` is that it can be much more concise than using an explicit `for` loop. However, when the list comprehension needs to be split over multiple lines, that conciseness can make the expression extremely difficult to read.

While PEP8 doesn't explicitly forbid multi-line list comprehensions, the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#274-decision) requires that each portion of a list comprehension fit on a single line (emphasis mine):

> **2.7 Comprehensions & Generator Expressions**
>
> Okay to use for simple cases. ***Each portion must fit on one line***: mapping expression, for clause, filter expression. Multiple for clauses or filter expressions are not permitted. ***Use loops instead when things get more complicated.***