# would like to get count of files in home dir in python

Tags: python

I saw this [How to count the number of files in a directory using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python)

and have this:

```
import os, os.path

print len([name for name in os.listdir(os.path.expanduser("~")) if os.path.isfile(name)])
```

but it always returns 0. How would i modify this to return the count of files?

thx

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe there are no files not stated with a dot in your home directory?

Comment: ... Is that actually coincidence? Because that's scarily close wording.

Comment: _"Works fine for me."_ - Only if your cwd is the home directory...

Comment: Actually I was just injecting some fun into this question and was hoping EVERYONE would answer the same way. Like a machine.

Comment: @Eric: You are right.  I did even test from a different directory, but by mere chance the only two pure files in my home directory also existed in that other directory.

Comment: Woops ^^ that is actually what I did too, damn those git repos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment, you're calling `os.path.isfile("somefile.ext")`. You need to call `os.path.isfile("~/somefile.ext")`.

```
import os

homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")
print len([
    name
    for name in os.listdir(homedir)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(homedir, name))
])
```

Or more concisely:

```
print sum(
    os.path.isfile(os.path.join(homedir, name)) for name in os.listdir(homedir)
)
```

Comment: Maybe your rather 'expanded' layout was the reason (I didn't downvote)

Comment: I expanded so that it fits the code box without scrollbars. Besides, I got the downvote before that.

Comment: @jamylak: Not sure that was an improvement. Is there any official document on how to wrap list comprehensions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809059/line-continuation-for-list-comprehensions-or-generator-expressions-in-python This post is what I based it off.

Comment: Gone for a compromise. I'm more of a wrap-and-indent than indent-by-column person.

Comment: @JoeFish: no, that's intentionally a generator expression rather than a list comprehension

Comment: (Note that it's redundant to import `os.path` explicitly.)

Comment: +1 for the version using `sum`. It is slightly non-obvious to write, but makes good sense to read.