# Pythonic Style for Multiline List Comprehension

Tags: python, coding-style, list-comprehension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Line continuation for list comprehensions or generator expressions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809059/line-continuation-for-list-comprehensions-or-generator-expressions-in-python)

What is the the most pythonic way to write a long list comprehension?  This list comprehension comes out to 145 columns:

```
memberdef_list = [elem for elem in from_cache(classname, 'memberdefs') if elem.argsstring != '[]' and 'std::string' in null2string(elem.vartype)]
```

How should it look if I break it into multiple lines?  I couldn't find anything about this in the Python style guides.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

PEP 8 kinda predates list comprehensions. I usually break these up over multiple lines at logical locations:

```
memberdef_list = [elem for elem in from_cache(classname, 'memberdefs')
                  if elem.argsstring != '[]' and 
                     'std::string' in null2string(elem.vartype)]
```

Mostly though, I'd forgo the involved test there in the first place:

```
def stdstring_args(elem):
    if elem.argstring == '[]':
        return False
    return 'std::string' in null2string(elem.vartype)

memberdef_list = [elem for elem in from_cache(classname, 'memberdefs')
                  if stdstring_args(elem)]
```

Comment: +1:I was about to suggest moving the lengthy test into a function

Comment: Really, here you want to use a filter.
`memberdef_list = filter(stdstring_args, from_cache(classname, 'memberdefs')`

Comment: @aterrel: that's a style choice really; `filter(stdstring_args, from_cache(classname, 'memberdefs'))` is fine too indeed.